# Why are nutrients from food absorbed more efficiently?

Tags: nutrition, digestive-system, digestion

It seems to be common knowledge that micronutrients such as vitamins are more easily absorbed by your body when in your diet versus supplements such as pills.
I am wondering what the reasons for this are.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there evidence to suggest that nutrients in vitamin capsules are not as readily absorbed as the same nutrients in whole foods?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/43710/is-there-evidence-to-suggest-that-nutrients-in-vitamin-capsules-are-not-as-readi)

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Note that "common knowledge" is often unreliable and this sort of claim should be referenced. We also encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). For example, the "Related" links on your post include a **very** similar question on this site.  ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: magnesium in veg and bananas is in molecules like Chlorophyll, which is better to eat than: Magnesium chloride. ...
Magnesium sulfate. 
Magnesium citrate. 
Magnesium oxide. There are billions of micro-nutrients from many elements. When the source is already, previously metabolized by another organism, the nutrients probably exist in a less concentrated matrix and in less strongly bonded organic forms than synthetic lab-nutrients. Laboratory and rock-sourced nutrients are often more concentrated and have not previously been metabolized, in molecules like globin and chlorophyll.